# Parsing of Message field of Event Log entry c#

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

How i can parse a particular field of event log message Or Replacement string using C#.  Ie  i need to parse the "Workstation Name"  from a security event log with id 4624, The sample log is given belowenter code here

```
Subject:
Security ID:        S-1-0-0
Account Name:       -
Account Domain:     -
Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         0

Impersonation Level:        -

New Logon:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-18
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3e7
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x4
    Process Name:       

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   - some data
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      -
    Authentication Package: -
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

I thought the order and count of replacement strings are same for every event with same event id but the length is not same. so how i can parse this string into corresponding object / or extract a particular field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to extract value of Workstation Name field one of the easiest ways would be using regular expressions

```
string fieldName = "Workstation Name";
var expression = new Regex(string.Format(@"\s*{0}:\s*-\s*(.+)\r\n", fieldName));
Match match = expression.Match(fileText);

if (match.Success)
{
  string workstationName = match.Groups[1];
  ...
}
```

Comment: i am appreciating your effort but  workstation Name was a sample, but i got the idea thanks

Comment: I extracted field name from expression in the code sample accordingly